# Base URL location in cPanel

Tags: database

I have restored my Magento1 store to another server and cannot reach the store on the Internet anymore. I need to change the Base URLs. Where can I find these stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store's base URL is stored in **`core_config_data`** table in database.

To change base URL, you will need to change all occurrences of **`web/unsecure/base_url`** and **`web/secure/base_url`** in **`core_config_data`** table.

Flush Magento's cache and check. Your problem should be gone.